# How to Track Absence of Key Value Pairs in a Python Dictionary Using Ternary Conditional

Tags: python

I am receiving two types of dictionary from requesters. some of them has an specific key called `portal` and some of the no like:

```
data = {
"Other_Key":"Other_Value",

"portal": {
    "isHosted": False,
    "portalServer": [
        {
            "type": "PHP",
            "itemID": "hshshdkdkd"
        },
        {
            "type": "ASP",
            "itemID": "5s55s5s5s"
        }
    ]
},
 "Other_Key":"Other_Value"
}
```

or in another format, simply like like this:

```
data = {
  "Other_Key_1":"Other_Value",
  "Other_Key_3":"Other_Value"
}
```

Now I want to grab the value of `Portal` so I used this ternary one line solution to check the existing of `Portal` in dictionary

```
status = data['portal']['isHosted'] if data['portal'] != "" else "NA"
print(status)
```

this is working fine as long as there is a `portal` node in the `data` but when is not contain the `portal` I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 5, in 
> status = data['portal']['isHosted'] if data['portal'] != "" else "NA"
> KeyError: 'portal'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that the "portal" value is an empty string "", it's that the "portal" key doesn't exist at all. So test that

```
status = data['portal']['isHosted'] if 'portal' in data else "NA"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are falsely assuming that `data['portal']` returns `""`

But if you run

```
data = {
  "Other_Key_1":"Other_Value",
  "Other_Key_3":"Other_Value"
}


print (data['portal'])
```

You will see

```
KeyError: 'portal'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the portal key exists in the dictionary like so

```
if 'portal' in data:
    #continue with if statement
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick method:

`status = data.get("portal", {}).get("isHosted", "NA")`